# Что делать если OnMessage, StartReceiving, не работают, а точнее пишут что нет библиотека, при том что она есть. Visual Studio 2022, C#

Tags: c#, библиотеки, бот, visual-studio-2022

появилась проблема в том что я пишу код для телеграмм бота, и основные библиотеки уже были скачаны и используются, но почему то не которые команды не видят библиотеку, не знаю что делать. Помогите чем нибудь, заранее спасибо.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пишу Телеграмм бота, активировал библиотеки, использую команду которая должна быть в составе библиотеки которую я скачал. После того как я его написал, пишет ошибку что мол нет using либо чёт так с ссылками ( написана ошибка на скриншоте ). Хочу понять какую мне надо библиотеку, чтоб исправить эту ошибку. Потому что все работает кроме этих команд который помечены красной волнистой полоской ( на скрине ).

Comment: А кто вам сказал, что они должны быть?

Comment: Делаю бота по гайду, у того человека у которого смотрю гайд, данные команды работают, и он показал какие библиотеки он установил для начало работы так скажем. У него они работают, у меня всё наоборот(.  У меня остался один вариант, и это в проблема в моей версии .NET, но вроде я посмотрел и там библиотеки должны работать на .NET 6.0 версии.

Comment: Ваш гайд устарел https://stackoverflow.com/a/70278665/12888024